# problem in plotting multiple lists using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I am writing a script which can be used to plot the country wise covid time-series data. It is working fine when I plot a single country but The scale at Y-axis is in appropriately printed. 
[Plot which I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kjEA.png) The Problem is after printing the maximum value for one country the y axis is extrapolated with smaller values to plot the data points of subsequent countries. 
The code for my script is as follows

```
import requests
from contextlib import closing
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/covid-19/master/data/countries-aggregated.csv"

def prepareCountryWiseData(country):
    countryWise = {}
    with closing(requests.get(url, stream=True)) as r:
        f = (line.decode('utf-8') for line in r.iter_lines())
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        active = []
        recovered = []
        dates = []
        for row in reader:    
             if row[1] == country:
                     dates.append(row[0])
                     active.append(row[2])
                     recovered.append(row[3])
        return (dates, active, recovered)

def plotCountryWiseData(countryList):
    plotable = []
    for country in countryList:
            dates,active,recovered = (prepareCountryWiseData(country))
            plt.plot(active)                
    plt.ylabel('active_cases')
    plt.legend(countryList)
    plt.show()
    plotCountryWiseData(['India','US','Italy'])
```

Comment: Can you use the pandas module for this project?

Comment: I have not used pandas . Now I have managed to find a hack of this problem. I have rounded the values and it matplotlib has handled it automatically. But I am unaware if some technical solution exists for it. If you know It using pandas please share your thoughts It will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use the [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) module your job would be much easier:

```
import pandas as pd, matplotlib.pyplot as plt

url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/covid-19/master/data/countries-aggregated.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(url)

fig,ax = plt.subplots()

for k,g in df[df['Country'].isin(['India','US','Italy'])].groupby('Country'):
    ax = g.plot(ax=ax,kind='line',x='Date',y='Confirmed',label=k) 

plt.gcf().suptitle('Active Cases')
plt.show()
```

Result:
[image]